# Instagram_Manage_Insights for Public Profiles

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

Based on the documentation of "Instagram_Manage_Insights" permission, it has been noted that page access token is mandatory for extracting stories from a page. I have this permission as advanced access. However, my usecase is related to extraction of statistics such as Engagement, Impression, Reach etc for Public Instagram Profiles (for which we don't have admin access or page access token). I wanted to know is there any possibility using graph API to perform this task?

Comment: What are you actually talking about, what does the permission to access insights, have to do with _"extracting stories from a page"_?

Comment: Our clients need to have a module in our app based on which they can track the stats of competitors stories in comparison to their own page stories stats. For this reason, I came up with this permission (Instagram_Manage_Insights) that says "Your app can also discover and read the profile info and media of other business profiles." Now, I have tried using both user and page access token but I am unable to retrieve the media of non-owned pages.

Comment: You don't get access to any insights for accounts you don't own/don't have admin access to.

Comment: Ok, can you please elaborate the meanings of the following line from FB API that instagram_manage_insights can provide the ability to read the media from other business profiles:

"The instagram_manage_insights permission allows your app to get access to insights for the Instagram account linked to a Facebook Page. Your app can also discover and read the profile info and media of other business profiles."

If this permission can discover the media than it means the stories of the competitors business pages can be extracted.

Comment: _"Your app can also discover and read the profile info and media of other business profiles."_ - you can get profile info and media objects from other businesses - but you _can't_ get any _insights_ data. Why should Facebook give sensitive information that is relevant to how your business performs, to your competition ...?

Comment: Yes, I get your point. What I am trying to say is that still no media is extracting using the defined endpoints from "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/instagram_manage_insights". If you know any endpoint for extracting media from a non-owned IG page, please do share. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media

Comment: I have tried this endpoint through "GET /{ig-user-id}/media". I have the permissions "instagram_basic", "pages_read_engagement", and "pages_show_list". It results in following:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'PROVIDED IG USER ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "Ba Blah Blah"
  }
}

Comment: Then you might need to do it directly via the business_discovery endpoint, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery#getting-media

Comment: Thanks for this endpoint. I have explored it and find it very useful related to my use case to get stats from different media of non-owned page. Through this I have tried extracting comments count, like counts that can help me in generating engagement rate. However, the returned media types are only FEEDs and REELs. It means there is no way to get story media object of competitors.

Comment: Sorry to ask here again. I have noted that some tools such as "getachoo.com" provides this functionality of Analyzing and Storing Instagram Stories for all public profiles. It means there must be some endpoint from FB that provides this functionality.

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily have to mean that, those services could also be scraping data.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much for your kind support